# making a program with foldr function

Tags: haskell

Assuming that I have this function:

```
 sales::Int->Int
```

this function returns the number of sales in a specific week,the weeks are organized as a series 0,1,2.... (it gets the number of week and return the number of sales in that week)

I need to define the function zeroWeeks : zeroWeeks gets an integer n and returns number of weeks that has 0 sales in range [0...n]. (list of weeks)

I have solved it with list comprehension,

this is how I solved it with list comprehension:

```
zeroWeeks:: Int -> Int
zeroWeeks n = length(ans)
              where ans = [w|w<-[0..n],sales w==0]
```

How can I solve it with foldr function and without using recursion ?

Comment: `\n -> length $ filter ((==0) . sales) [0..n]` or if you really want to use a fold: `\n -> foldr (\x -> if sales x == 0 then (+1) else id) 0 [0..n]`

Comment: Should the function signature remain the same, or can it accept the list of weeks directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a helper function `f` that returns 1 if there were 0 sales for some week, and 0 otherwise. Then you can compose `+` and `f` to map "zero weeks" to 1 and everything else to 0, then take the sum.

```
zeroWeeks :: [Int] -> Int
zeroWeeks = foldr ((+) . f) 0
  where f w | sales w == 0 = 1
            | otherwise = 0
```

Comment: does it first run f on each element of the list and only then it sums them up with the + operator ? or is it doing it together on each element ? run f then add it to sum... run f on second element then add it to sum...

Comment: @Shiran It runs over the list once, first applying `f` to each element and then adding the result to the sum.

Answer (score 1):

I think its a good idea to look how your function would look like using manual recursion instead of list comprehensions:

```
zeroWeeks :: [Int] -> Int
zeroWeeks [] = 0
zeroWeeks (x:xs) = (if sales x == 0 then 1 else 0)  + zeroWeeks xs
```

Now, lets look at how `foldr` is defined

```
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

As you can see, foldr is kind a high level pattern for defining functions similar oto zeroWeeks, with `z` standing in for the base case and  `f` standing in for the operation we do in the recursive case. In zeroWeeks's case, its easy to see that we want to make `z` to be 0 and the tricky part is finding the f. Basically, what we need to do is make the `x` and `zeroWeeks xs` as explicit parameters instead of parts of a biggger expression:

```
zeroWeeks (x:xs) = (\x sum -> (if sales x == 0 then sum + 1 else sum)) x (zeroSum xs)
```

The end result is thus

```
zeroSum xs = foldr (\x sum -> (if sales x == 0 then sum + 1 else sum)) 0 xs
```

Although I would highly recommend refactoring that big lambda function into a separate functions for readability, like Benjamin Kovach did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24336594).

Comment: so foldr gets 3 arguments:  1. lambda function , 2. base case =0 and 3.  a list = xs .    and the lambda function gets 2 arguments : x and sum.... how does the lambda function work ?

Comment: and what is ur sum ? how do initialize it to 0 ?

Comment: sum is just a function parameter in an anonymous function. I am passing `zeroSum xs` to it. BTW, variables in Haskell are immutable. Its more like giving a name to a value and it doesn't really make sense to "initialize" and then "update".